# How to represent percentage and ratio in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

For the sake of simplicity, assume that there are 60 women and 40 men in my class.

I want to say the following statements. Are they correct?

1. The ratio of men to women is 2 to 3.

   クラスの女性に対する男性の割合は２対３だ。(Type A)
2. The ratio of men to women is 2 to 3.

   クラスの男性の女性に対する割合は２対３だ。(Type B)
3. Women is 3/2 of men.

   女性の割合は男性の割合の２分の３だ。
4. Women is 60% of the class.

   女性はクラスの６０％だ。(Type C)
5. Women is 60% of the class.

   女性の割合はクラスの６０％だ。(Type D)
6. Women is 60% of the class.

   女性は６割だ。(Type E)
7. Women is 60% of the class.

   女性の割合は６割だ。(Type F)

Any other possible proportions are also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sentences look pretty good overall, but:

- The first two sentences may be correct, but confusing to me. If you want to use A対B, it's better to clarify which number corresponds to which sex. Try something like these:

  > - クラスの《男女比｛だんじょひ｝￤性別の割合》は、男性対女性が2対3だ。
  > - ...男性(が)2、対、女性(が)3だ。
  > - ...男性(が)2に対して女性(が)3だ。
- 3分の2 (= 2/3 = 66.7%) is fairly common, but 2分の3 (= 3/2 = 150%) is not something we say in daily life, although it's mathematically correct. Most people have to stop for a moment and think what it means. Instead, you can say 「1.5倍だ」。
- (Type C–F) Some sentences lack a topic which serves as the denominator. And when we say something like this, isn't (うちの)クラス the normal topic?

  > - うちのクラスは女性が《6割￤60%》だ。
  > - うちのクラスの女性の割合は《6割￤60%》だ。
  > - うちのクラスは《6割￤60%》が女性だ。
  > - うちのクラスの《6割￤60%》は女性だ。
- If you do want to use 女性 as the topic, it's better to use an appropriate verb.

  > - 女性はクラスの《6割￤60%》を《占める￤構成する》。 (sounds like a math problem...)